# Pass value of JSONObject to case of getItem

Tags: java, android

There i am again with the car story. In the car adapter i would like to through all values like i am doing now. From each field i would like to take the value.

In the getItem function, i would to pass to case 0 the fields/values(name and description) with index 0 of the car object. For case 1 i would like to pass the fields/values with index 1.

CarAdapter.java

```
public void onEvent(CarResponse reponse) throws JSONException {
data = reponse.getData();
car = data.getJSONArray("carList");

 for(int i = 0 ; i < car.length() ; i++){
     JSONObject firstCar =  car.getJSONObject(i);
     CAR_NAAM = firstCar.getString("name");
     CAR_DESCRIPTION = firstCar.getString("description");
    }
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

switch (position){
    case 0:
        coffeeName = CAR_NAAM;
        description = CAR_DESCRIPTION;


    case 1:
        carName = CAR_NAAM;
        description = CAR_DESCRIPTION;

}
return CarFragment.newInstance(carName, description);
}
```

Can anyone of u help me in the right path? If the problem is not clear i can detail it more.

P.S : i know you can achieve this by making loads of variables, and getting the values one by one manually. My program would become heavy because of that. That's the worst solution i think.

Comment: why not save the JSONArray and then retrieve the data with `position` as index ?

Comment: what is the problem exactly, do you get an exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `JSONObject` from `JSONArray` using `position`. You can use the below code.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    JSONObject objCar = car.get(position);
    String carName = objCar.getString("name");
    String description = objCar.getString("description");
    return CarFragment.newInstance(carName, description);
}
```

Comment: Does this keep it dynamic? I have 2 cars in the object. How will it know  that it should make 2 fragments ?